# How to search/locate text/pattern within a (long) e-mail being composed in built-in ios mail app (iPad, 14.8.1)?

Tags: ios, mail.app, search

Not trying to find a specific message containing the string, but within an e-mail being composed.
Would be trivial on a computer or even using webmail (COMMAND-F, etc), but can't figure out how to search for text/pattern *within* a (long) e-mail being composed in the built-in ios Mail app (iPad, 14.8.1).  (Scrolling through screen after screen, scanning by eye is not the most efficient.)